# Boost multi-index container vs a multi-level mapping container based on std::unordered_map (map of maps)

Tags: c++, boost, std, unordered-map, boost-multi-index

I recently found boost::multi_index_container and I'm curious about his performance compared to my own implementation of a similar container based on multi-level mapping and defined as:

```
typedef int      Data;
typedef uint64_t MainKey;
typedef uint64_t SecondaryKey;

typedef std::unordered_map<SecondaryKey, Data>       SecondaryMap;
typedef std::unordered_map<PrimaryKey, SecondaryMap> PrimaryMap;
```

The key ordering is not important. The fast lookup is important and for this I'm using something like:

```
// find primaryKey=10 and secondaryKey=30
PrimaryMap m;
....
auto i1 = m.find( 10);
if ( i1 != m.end())
{
    auto& secondary = i1->second;
    auto i2 = secondary.find( 30);
    if ( i2 != secondary.end())
    {
        found = true;
        ....
    }
}
```

I would like to know what would be

- the most closest configuration of boost::multi_index_container to match my implementation
- the fastest way to search by primary key and secondary key.

I have tried to configure the template but I'm not sure if this is the best solution:

```
struct RecordKey
{
    MainKey         mainKey;
    SecondaryKey    secondaryKey;

    RecordKey( const MainKey mainKey, SecondaryKey secondaryKey):
        mainKey( mainKey),
        secondaryKey( secondaryKey)
    {}
};

struct Record: public RecordKey
{
    Data data;

    Record( const MainKey mainKey = 0, const SecondaryKey secondaryKey = 0, const Data& data = 0):
        RecordKey( mainKey, secondaryKey),
        data( data)
    {}
};


struct MainKeyTag {};
struct SecondaryKeyTag {};
struct CompositeKeyTag {};

using boost::multi_index_container;
using namespace boost::multi_index;

typedef boost::multi_index_container<Record,
    indexed_by  <   /*random_access<>,*/
                    hashed_non_unique<tag<MainKeyTag>,      BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER( RecordKey, MainKey, mainKey) >,
                    hashed_non_unique<tag<SecondaryKeyTag>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER( RecordKey, SecondaryKey, secondaryKey) >,
                    hashed_unique<tag<CompositeKeyTag>,     composite_key<Record,   member<RecordKey, MainKey, &RecordKey::mainKey>,
                                                                                    member<RecordKey, SecondaryKey, &RecordKey::secondaryKey> > > > > RecordContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multi-index container must have 3 indexes:

- index for main key: `hashed` - because `std::unordered_map` is hashed,
  `non_unique` - because multiple records could have same key;
- index for secondary key: same as for the main key;
- index for composite key: `hashed` - because `std::unordered_map` is hashed, `unique` - because the tuples (main key, secondary key) are unique in the map of maps
  structure.

The container is defined as:

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container<Record, indexed_by <
    hashed_non_unique<tag<MainKeyTag>,      BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER( RecordKey, MainKey, mainKey) >,
    hashed_non_unique<tag<SecondaryKeyTag>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER( RecordKey, SecondaryKey, secondaryKey) >,
    hashed_unique<tag<CompositeKeyTag>,     
    composite_key<Record,
        member<RecordKey, MainKey, &RecordKey::mainKey>,
        member<RecordKey, SecondaryKey, &RecordKey::secondaryKey> > > > > RecordContainer;
```

The insertion is:

```
RecordContainer c;
c.insert( Record( 10, 20, 0));
c.insert( Record( 10, 30, 1));
c.insert( Record( 10, 40, 2));
```

The lookup is:

```
auto& index = c.get<CompositeKeyTag>();
auto pos = index.find( boost::make_tuple( 10, 30)); // don't use std::make_tuple!
if ( pos != index.end())
{
    found = true;
    data = pos->data;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can have your cake and eat it too, by choosing ordered (instead of hashed) indexes in BMI.

There is a nice property of *ordered* composite indexes that allows you to query by partial keys, so you need only define the composite index to be able to query by main index too:

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    Record,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_non_unique< tag<CompositeKeyTag>, 
        composite_key<Record, 
                    member<RecordKey, MainKey, &RecordKey::mainKey>,
                    member<RecordKey, SecondaryKey, &RecordKey::secondaryKey>
    > > > > RecordContainer;
```

Now you can either query by `mainKey`:

```
range = index.equal_range(10);
```

Or by composite:

```
range = index.equal_range(boost::make_tuple(10,30));
```

Background:

- [boost::multi_index composite keys efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313085/boostmulti-index-composite-keys-efficiency/20316447#20316447)
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#composite_keys

Here's a full demo <kbd>**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a1c266683b9ee9a)**</kbd>:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using MainKey      = uint64_t;
using SecondaryKey = uint64_t;
using Data         = std::string;

struct RecordKey
{
    MainKey         mainKey;
    SecondaryKey    secondaryKey;

    RecordKey( const MainKey mainKey, SecondaryKey secondaryKey):
        mainKey( mainKey),
        secondaryKey( secondaryKey)
    {}
};

struct Record: public RecordKey
{
    Data data;

    Record( const MainKey mainKey = 0, const SecondaryKey secondaryKey = 0, const Data& data = 0):
        RecordKey( mainKey, secondaryKey),
        data( data)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Record const& r) {
        return os << " Record[" << r.mainKey << ", " << r.secondaryKey << ", " << r.data << "]";
    }
};

struct MainKeyTag {};
struct SecondaryKeyTag {};
struct CompositeKeyTag {};

using boost::multi_index_container;
using namespace boost::multi_index;

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
    Record,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_non_unique< tag<CompositeKeyTag>, 
        composite_key<Record, 
                    member<RecordKey, MainKey, &RecordKey::mainKey>,
                    member<RecordKey, SecondaryKey, &RecordKey::secondaryKey>
    > > > > RecordContainer;


int main()
{
    RecordContainer records;
    records.insert(Record(10, 20, "12"));
    records.insert(Record(10, 30, "13"));
    records.insert(Record(10, 30, "13 - need not be unique!"));
    records.insert(Record(30, 40, "34"));
    records.insert(Record(30, 50, "35"));
    records.insert(Record(50, 60, "56"));
    records.insert(Record(50, 70, "57"));
    records.insert(Record(70, 80, "78"));

    std::cout << "\nAll records:\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for (auto const& r : records)
        std::cout << r << "\n";

    {
        std::cout << "\nAll records with (main) == (10):\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        auto& index = records.get<0>();
        auto range = index.equal_range(10);
        for (auto const& r : boost::make_iterator_range(range.first, range.second))
            std::cout << r << "\n";
    }

    {
        std::cout << "\nAll records with (main,secondary) == (10,30):\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        auto& index = records.get<0>();
        auto range = index.equal_range(boost::make_tuple(10,30));
        for (auto const& r : boost::make_iterator_range(range.first, range.second))
            std::cout << r << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
All records:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Record[10, 20, 12]
 Record[10, 30, 13]
 Record[10, 30, 13 - need not be unique!]
 Record[30, 40, 34]
 Record[30, 50, 35]
 Record[50, 60, 56]
 Record[50, 70, 57]
 Record[70, 80, 78]

All records with (main) == (10):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Record[10, 20, 12]
 Record[10, 30, 13]
 Record[10, 30, 13 - need not be unique!]

All records with (main,secondary) == (10,30):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Record[10, 30, 13]
 Record[10, 30, 13 - need not be unique!]
```

Comment: Thanks but are you suggesting the ordered variant has no performance penalties for searching compared to the hashed variant? I want to do performance tests to find out which is faster, boost multi-index container or my own construction. I would need an index for primary key, and index for secondary key and a combined index for both keys. IMHO hashed should be faster that ordered.

Comment: @Flaviu ordered vs. hashed always depends on access patterns. But seeing how you seem to think that a map-of-maps would suit your access patterns, I'm pretty confident that ordered-composites are a good match (it's what you want, using two cascaded binary searches only). If you /also/ require direct lookup by complete composite, you may consider adding a hashed composite index ***as well***. However, keep in mind this will have a nontrivial overhead on each (key)modifying operation on the container.

Comment: I was able myself to insert and search using an ordered boost::multi_index_container but I was looking for a hashed or a random_access solution. Is the hashed composite key configuration the closest one to my own construction regarding the lookup?

Comment: Depends on what key. Also aging more indices isn't free. Consider external helpers and always be profiling.

Comment: I have also addressed similar questions here, where i had a little more context information to make additional suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474577/using-boost-multi-index-like-relational-db/26476131#26476131 In particular it might appeal to you for the random access aspect  of your requirements  (that you haven't clarified)

Comment: I will accept an solution that uses hashed_non_unique composite index instead of ordered_non_unique composite index. Perhaps only few changes are need in your example.

Comment: OK, so the hashed indexes doesn't support that kind of lookup?

Comment: Yay. You got the point :) Do look at the additional suggestions I linked 2 hours ago. I have a feeling you could benefit from a strategy like those

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I just had the impression there could be a more straight forward way to lookup instead of using equal_range. In conclusion a multi-index container with ordered indexes is the closest possible configuration to match my construction. Perhaps in the future a call like `m.get<CompositeKeyTag>().find( make_tuple( 10, 30))` could do that kind of lookup.

Comment: @Flaviu erm, `find()` is already working. It's just something that's not very useful with non-unique indices. (And certainly not with partial keys)

Comment: I need only unique indices. Considering this, could I use find() on the composite index having primaryKey=10 and secondaryKey=30?

Comment: Hahaha. Yes, in that case, just a **[`hashed_unique<composite_key<...>>` would do](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3ab2604b2179f1c)** (note that the duplicate (10,30) insert was ignored as per the docs). I'm a bit surprised that the question was [posed in the way it was](https://www.google.nl/search?q=xy+problem) then :)

Comment: :)) The unique composite key was needed from the beginning because std::unordered_map doesn't accept duplicates. Indeed it was partially the XY problem. Meantime I found the issue of my solution: on `find()` call `std::make_tuple` was used instead of `boost::make_tuple`... but this doesn't necessary mean no other configurations of BMI could be closer to my own construction (I'm still not sure about the random_access<> usage). Regards

Answer (score 1):

Similar situation, but boost was not allowed in my group so implemented in following way, in case of lookup by secondary key, only one lookup is required not two:

```
    #include<map>
    using namespace std;

    template<class PrimaryKey, class SecondaryKey, class Data>
    class MyMultiIndexedMap
    {
        private:
        typedef map<PrimaryKey, Data*> PT;
        typedef map<SecondaryKey, Data*> ST;

        PT pri_data_;
        ST sec_data_;

        public:
        bool insert(PrimaryKey pk, SecondaryKey sk, Data *data);
        Data* findBySecondaryKey(SecondaryKey sk);       
        Data* findByPrimaryKey(PrimaryKey pk);    
    };
```